# Suggestions regarding Android list item design

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-design-library

So, I need a list of items in my app and I want the item layout to be similar to those presented in the android material design guidelines. I've searched a lot but I didn't find ways to recreate the *three-line list* example:
[image]

I don't want to copy it, I just need some guidelines on how to create something similar with the partial separator and the circular image view.

I'm guessing they're using `RecyclerView`, right?

What library would you recommend me for the circular image view? I've used [this one before](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView), but maybe there are some better alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` with a custom adapter.

Your **row.xml** shoud look something like this (just add some padding, bolding,...).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_download_cloud_green"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="One"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Two"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Three"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/grey"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Be sure to disable the seperator on your ListView/RecyclerView, you have it in your row.

Also, using the library for **CircleImageView** is the right thing to do (at least to my knowledge). Have used the same library before, and it is awsome!

Comment: Thank you! That last **View** was what I needed. I will continue to use that library.

Comment: It isn't that. In the example, the second part is just one text view with some bolded text and some normal text but you used three different text views.